# Cannot open iReports 6

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

i tried installing the latest version of iReport. installation was successful but  now while opening it is giving me error. the Slash screen opens and closes.

error :

[image: the Erroor i am getting:]

my config file :

```
# ${HOME} will be replaced by user home directory according to platform
default_userdir="${HOME}/.${APPNAME}/5.6.0"
default_mac_userdir="${HOME}/Library/Application Support/${APPNAME}/5.6.0"

# options used by the launcher by default, can be overridden by explicit
# command line switches
default_options="-J-Xms256m -J-Xmx512m -J-Dorg.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.level=1000 -J-XX:MaxPermSize=512m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dnetbeans.exception.report.min.level=99999 "
# for development purposes you may wish to append: -J-Dnetbeans.logger.console=true -J-ea

# default location of JDK/JRE, can be overridden by using --jdkhome <dir> switch
#jdkhome="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java"
jdkhome="\jdk1.6.0_45"
# clusters' paths separated by path.separator (semicolon on Windows, colon on Unices)
#extra_clusters=
```

please help me

Answer (score 0):

Look at this line

```
# default location of JDK/JRE, can be overridden by using --jdkhome <dir> switch
#jdkhome="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java"
jdkhome="\jdk1.6.0_45"
# clusters' paths separated by path.separator (semicolon on Windows, colon on Unices)
#extra_clusters=
```

What you need is to set an environement varialble JDK_HOME that points to the path of your JDK installation  , or update your config file to point to the path where JDK installed

Answer (score 0):

a)  Once installed, go to its `\etc` folder, e.g., `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jaspersoft\iReport-5.6.0\etc` and add write permissions (for yourself) to the readonly file `ireport.conf`, of which you show an example output.

b) Open `ireport.conf` w/ an editor like Notepad++ , and add the line for your jdk home, e.g., `jdkhome="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_71"` (instead of just jdkhome="\jdk1.6.0_45"). Note: on Win OS you might need to use the escaped backslash.